# Custom messages in Spring security with UserDetailsService implementation and Exceptions

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I'm working with Spring Security 2.0.7. It had been implemented the `UserDetailsService`  with a `preAuthenticatedUserDetailsService` bean.

It's working fine. Now I want to add a new custom error messages. 
In the method `loadUserByUsername` I want to add some custom bussines logic.
For ex. based on some attribute, I don't want the user to log in so I throw a `UsernameNotFoundException` with a custom message.

Spring is the one who handdle the exception and set it to the session, but when I retrive the exception from the session with "SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION" key I get a "Bad credentials" message.

At the moment is fixed with a nasty workarround, mostly I want to understand what happend!

Ideas?

Ps. I read a lot of this issue here in SO but mostly all with Spring security 3.0

Comment: Which is basically what you want, from a security perspective. You don't want to tell the user that the **username** doesn't exist. A hacker then goes on to the next username, until he gets a different message (that the password was wrong) he will then start hacking the password.

Comment: Yeah, I get what you mean, but this is business logic, like for example the credentials are OK, but the password expired,  or user is not yet active. The user should see those messages.

Comment: Please elaborate in your question as currently it is unclear what you want. Your comment and question don't relate as you are talking about a `UsernameNotFoundException` which has no relation to expired credentials of not active users.

Comment: The firm of the method throws the `UsernameNotFoundException`. Here is it:
`org.springframework.security.userdetails.UserDetails loadUserByUsername(java.lang.String s) throws org.springframework.security.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException, org.springframework.dao.DataAccessException;`
But I will try to clarify the question!

Comment: Spring will always display a 'Bad Credentials' it will not give more information. You can check how the exception is handled in the `ExceptionTranslationFilter` and the other components it uses (like an  `EntryPoint` etc.).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to close it. As @M. Deinum mentioned in the comments. Spring handle this way for security purposes. The implementation can be seen in the [ExceptionTranslationFilter](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework.security/spring-security-web/3.0.2.RELEASE/org/springframework/security/web/access/ExceptionTranslationFilter.java) class.

Answer (score 0):

That problem was nagging me for a while before finding an efficient & easy solution.

The issue was resolved by using a custom AuthenticationFailureHandler (that is added to HttpSecurity configuration) to get the custom error message from UserDetailsService before sending it back to login page as error parameter

The custom AuthenticationFailureHandler is defined like following:

```
@Component("CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler")
public class CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler implements AuthenticationFailureHandler {

    private RedirectStrategy redirectStrategy = new DefaultRedirectStrategy();

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationFailure(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
            AuthenticationException exception) throws IOException, ServletException {
        String encodedErrorMessage = null;
        // Get AuthenticationException that was thrown in UserDetailsService, retrieve the error message and attach it as encoded error parameter of the error login page
        if (exception != null) {
            String errorMessage = exception.getMessage();
            encodedErrorMessage = Base64.getUrlEncoder().encodeToString(errorMessage.getBytes());
        }
        redirectStrategy.sendRedirect(request, response, "/login?error=" + encodedErrorMessage);
    }
}
```

Then the CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler is configured in WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter (also the configureGlobal is updated) as following:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    
    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler customAuthenticationFailureHandler;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and().formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll()
                .failureHandler(customAuthenticationFailureHandler) // Add failure handler class
        // ...
        // ...
    }
    
    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(authProvider());
    }
    
    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    public AuthenticationProvider authProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider impl = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        impl.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        impl.setPasswordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder());
        // setHideUserNotFoundExceptions is set to false in order to get the exceptions CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler  
        impl.setHideUserNotFoundExceptions(false);
        return impl;
    }
}
```

The exceptions related to user account (UsernameNotFoundException) are always thrown in UserDetailsService interface:

```
@Service
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService{
    private UserDetails getUserByUsername(String username) {
        UserDTO userDTO = userService.findByUsername(username);
        if (userDTO == null) {
            // Custom error message when no account was found by the given username 
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("No user account was found by the username [" + username + "]");
        }
        Date expirationDate = userDTO.getExpirationDate();
        if(expirationDate != null) {
            if(expirationDate.before(new Date())) {
                // Custom error message when the account is expired 
                throw new UsernameNotFoundException("The user account [" + username + "] is expired");
            }
        }
        // Can add more UsernameNotFoundException with custom messages based on functional requirements
        // ...
        List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities = getGrantedAutorities(userDTO);
        return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(userDTO.getUsername(), userDTO.getPassword(), grantedAuthorities);
    }
}
```

The exceptions are handled in CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler in order to send the custom error messages (encoded using Base64) like following :

```
@Component("CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler")
public class CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler implements AuthenticationFailureHandler {

    private RedirectStrategy redirectStrategy = new DefaultRedirectStrategy();

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationFailure(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
            AuthenticationException exception) throws IOException, ServletException {
        String encodedErrorMessage = null;
        // Get AuthenticationException that was thrown in UserDetailsService, retrieve the error message and attach it as encoded error parameter of the error login page
        if (exception != null) {
            String errorMessage = exception.getMessage();
            encodedErrorMessage = Base64.getUrlEncoder().encodeToString(errorMessage.getBytes());
        }
        redirectStrategy.sendRedirect(request, response, "/login?error=" + encodedErrorMessage);
    }
}
```

Then the error message is retrieved in the Controller like following:

```
@GetMapping(value = {"/login", "/"})
public String login(Model model, @RequestParam(name="error", required = false) String error) {
    if (error != null) {
        byte[] decodedBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(error);
        String decodedString = new String(decodedBytes);
        model.addAttribute("error", decodedString);
    }

    return "login";
}
```